# disable editing in layouts files in a published Android library

Tags: android, android-layout, android-library

I have made a Library Project.I have made a Jar file for all sources files so it could not be edited.But now I also want disable the changes in layout's xml files in that library project.I have googled it in many ways but not found any solution to this.Is that any way to stop editing in layout files ?
Please let me know if is there any way to do this.
Thanks.

Comment: I think it is not possible to protect the xml files as android res files can not be embedded in a jar file. One way is to generate all your layouts from code (no xml).

Comment: but i have too many layouts and it will be like labour work for me if i will go that way.is there any other suggestion?